# How do I add a folder to a GitHub repo using the web gui?

Tags: github

I see that I can edit the file pathway while creating a file to create a new folder but I don't see how I can create a new folder without creating a new file.

This isn't answered in other questions because they don't use the web gui and don't explain that GitHub doesn't track folders.

Comment: Not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when naming the file, first put the name of the folder follewed by a slash:

foldername/

it will automatically convert to a folder, and present a new text box to either create another folder or the final file.

[image: github adding a file within a folder]

Comment: But if I'm uploading a file then I can't name the file.

Comment: This does not create an empty directory. git doesn't track directories. It tracks files and content.

Comment: As PeeHaa said, empty directories won't be tracked.  You'd need to first create a new file within the new directory, then you can separately upload the files directly to that directory.

Comment: Thank you, senorsmile and PeeHaa. It is clear to me now. My work around is to create a temporary file in order to create the directory and then upload my files to that new folder and then delete the original temporary. It seems clunky so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: PeeHaa, you reported my question as the same as an unrelated question. My account is new and this triggered an automatic ban on me for posting predominately "low-quality content". I saw your downvotes too. I feel like you should treat new members better and make reports/downvotes in good faith.

Comment: I think ultimately using either the desktop client or the command line is the way to go.  This is probably a usability "bug" that you could suggest an improvement to GitHub.